# what does resetting a mock do in mockito? What state of mock gets reset and what stays the same?

Tags: mockito

What happens when a `mock` is reset.

Say the mock is

```
val mockHelperMethods = mock(classOf[HelperMethods])
  when(mockHelperMethods.getUniqueID()).thenReturn(UUID.fromString("11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111"))
  when(mockHelperMethods.bucketIDFromEmail(ArgumentMatchers.any())).thenReturn(1)
```

If i call `reset(mockHelperMethods)`, would I have to again do `when` and `thenReturn`?

What state of mock gets reset and what stays the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you call `reset(mock)`, then you will need to redefine mock's behavior (by `when`). Otherwise, its methods will start to return default values (null, 0, "" etc.) again.

See [docs](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.25.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#17) for `reset` method.

Need to say that resetting mocks is considered a bad practice. It indicates that you test more than one thing inside your test method.